# How to enable PayPal Payment Method in Magento for INR Base Currency

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.9

I am using *Magento CE 1.9.2.1*.

I just configured PayPal Payment Method in my website and my base currency is INR.

When I am trying to place order with PayPal Payment method it is redirecting back to my Cart Page and it is displaying the following error in my exception.log file.

> PayPal NVP gateway errors: Currency is not supported (#10605:
>   Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional
>   error messages for details)

I know the PayPal Payment Gateway will not support INR currency code but i can't change my Base Currency because all of my products are uploading from one ERP.

How can I make it working with INR as Base Currency ?

And i have tried the following way but still no use

**Go to app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php**

Change this array

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

To

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN','NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB','INR');
```

Comment: is your issue solved?